# Getting a link which is associated with a button on the webpage

Tags: android, button, android-webview

Is there a way to get the link which is associated with a button on a web page on android? Downloading the web page by using a httpconnection gives out the source of the webpage but not the link which is associated with a button on the webpage. I can see the url of the button by inspecting elements on the web page on a browser but not by viewing the source.

Comment: This might help
https://medium.com/@kpbird/android-webview-detect-html-element-on-click-263431c52e01

Comment: @SuhaylSH uhh, no, I'm not going to show the webpage, I need just the link that a button on the webpage is associated with. Like for eg, say there's a button called register on facebook.com and lets say when you click on the button it takes you to the page www.facebook.com/register. I need that link without clicking on that button. I hope this is a bit more clear? Thanks for answering :)

Comment: Use JSoup:
https://medium.com/@ssaurel/learn-to-parse-html-pages-on-android-with-jsoup-2a9b0da0096f

Comment: @SuhaylSH It doesn't seem to work. I think its because the said button is generated after i go to the webpage. Maybe its because of that?